# Perl search for unique lines and corresponding file names

Tags: perl, command-line

I was  using `perl -ne '$h{$_}++; END {print grep { $h{$_} == 1 } %h}' <a.txt <b.txt` to get the unique lines of both files. While it's printing all the unique lines of these two files, I want it to print the corresponding name of the file which contains these unique lines.

Is there a way in perl command to accomplish this?

p.s.Please forgive my poor English. I hope I got myself clear.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the name of the file from [`$ARGV`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Here is an example where I put the name of the file in another hash `%n`:

```
perl -nE 'chomp; $h{$_}++; $n{$_}=$ARGV; 
  END {say for map {"$n{$_}: $_"} grep { $h{$_} == 1 } keys %h}' a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: Hi @Håkon Hægland, this works wonderfully. :) Thanks so much.